# How can I make the rows for an audio app in CarPlay tappable?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, carplay

I'm new to CarPlay and understand it's similar to UITableViewController but slightly different and not able to make the rows capable of being tapped to run a function/code. Not much info online on this, no samples. Apple engineer told me they will provide a sample for audio apps soon on their developer site. So far I have everything running and that's all I believe I'm missing. I have entitlements from Apple, added what's needed in plist. Everything displays fine in actual CarPlay device. I have two tabs with sample items in them, one I need to run function for streaming live media when tapped, and the other to a podcast list, need to load list and make them tappable to run functions for that.

This is what I've been testing so far:

```
protocol MPPlayableContentDelegate {
    func dataReceived(data: String)
}


//Check data:       indexPath.count == 2 && indexPath[0] == 0 && indexPath[1] == 0
class CarplayDataSource: NSObject, MPPlayableContentDataSource, MPPlayableContentDelegate {

    let dataStore = NSObject()
    var dataHelper: DataHelper!
    var podcastData = [PodcastObject]()

    var podcastItem = PlayerViewController()

    var delegate: MPPlayableContentDelegate! = nil

    func dataReceived(data: String) {
        delegate?.dataReceived(data:"data received")
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("CARPLAY: init")
        self.dataReceived(data: "data is now received")
    }

    func numberOfChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
        print("CARPLAY: number of items")

        if indexPath.indices.count == 0 {
            print("CARPLAY: number of items > indices.count == 0 > return 2")
            return 2
        } else if indexPath.indices.count == 1 {
            print("CARPLAY: number of items > indices.count == 1 > return 1")
            return 1
        }
        return 1
    }


    func contentItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> MPContentItem? {
        print("CARPLAY: contentItem at indexpath")

        let indexCount = indexPath.count
        let tabIndex = indexPath[0]
        if indexCount == 1 {

            if tabIndex == 0 {
                let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "Tab \(tabIndex)")

                item.title = "Radio"
                item.isContainer = true
                item.isPlayable = false
                item.artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "radio-carplay"))
                return item
            } else {

                let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "Tab \(tabIndex)")
                item.title = "Podcasts"
                item.isContainer = true
                item.isPlayable = false
                item.artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "recordings-carplay"))
                return item
            }
        } else if indexCount == 2 {

            if tabIndex == 0 {
                let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "Tab \(tabIndex) Item")
                item.title = "Listen Live" //= "Tab \(tabIndex) Item"
                item.subtitle = "Radio Subtitle!"
                item.isPlayable = true
                item.artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menulogo"))

                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    item.isStreamingContent = true
                }
                return item
            } else {
                let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "Tab \(tabIndex) Item")
                item.title = "Coming Soon!" //for now since I don't now how to bring the list in
                item.isPlayable = true
                return item
            }

        }
        return nil

    }

    func contentItem(forIdentifier identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping (MPContentItem?, Error?) -> Swift.Void){
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use:

```
- (void)playableContentManager:(MPPlayableContentManager *)contentManager initiatePlaybackOfContentItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler;
```

It's part of MPPlayableContentDelegate. From there I just call the regular play methods from my app. Hope this helps.